# Add mouseover to outliers but not other points?

Tags: r, highcharts

I'd like to plot a large scatterplot using the `highcharter` package, but only allow mouse over on a few outliers. Is there a way to enable mouseTracking on one series but not the other?

```
df <- data.frame( x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000) )
df$sig <- ifelse( abs(df$x) > 2, "signif", "not")

library(highcharter)
hc <- highchart() %>%
   hc_add_series_df(df, type = "scatter", group=sig)
```

Right now I can only disable mouse over on all points, but the `hc_plotOptions` says something about using a series array?

```
hc_plotOptions(hc,  scatter = list( enableMouseTracking= FALSE  ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of way to do what you want.

I think the simplest is use:

```
hchart(df, "scatter", hcaes(x, y, group = sig), enableMouseTracking = c(FALSE, TRUE))
```

(Note this is the development version of highcharter.)

Which is same as:

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = df %>% filter(sig == "not"), type = "scatter", enableMouseTracking = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = df %>% filter(sig == "signif"), type = "scatter", enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
```

Or

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(data = list_parse(df %>% filter(sig == "not")), type = "scatter", enableMouseTracking = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list_parse(df %>% filter(sig == "signif")), type = "scatter", enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll get the development version, but I will miss hc_add_series_df.

Comment: Hey, sorry, but there's no need for `hc_add_series_df`!! or `hc_add_series_xts` etc, because `hc_add_series` is now a generic function (like `plot` for example) so you just need to replace `hc_add_series_df` with `hc_add_series`